# Scroll list up screen, one click per item, with previous items scrolling up towards top

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

What I'd like to do is a bit like a Credits animation but not continuous.

On click: Item scrolls in from the bottom, previous item scrolls up in sync (but not off the top of the screen) and fades slightly to draw attention to the new item.  Then pause with the new item on the screen until the next click.  The idea being that the audience could still read the previous item if need be but their attention would be drawn to the new item.

Is this possible?

Comment: At a guess, not quite the way you are describing. Unless I am mistaken, the best you might hope for I think is a Float In for the previous text combined with an additional color transition, with the new text using a Fly In from the bottom.

Comment: @Anaksunaman: Is it possible to Float further up the screen without disappearing off the screen completely?

Comment: Not so as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you exactly imagine it, but you can do it with some work.

I've managed to do something like this:

[image]

It involves placing black squares with transparency and moving lines animations, like in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, it's a nice solution.  How do you get it to scroll up one item at a time?  I tried Credits and Float In but neither seem to work in the way your animation does.

Comment: What I did was to group the three text boxes, then I used the "Lines" motion effect from the "Motion Paths" category. I used 3 line motion effects for each position of the group. Having three effects you can control each motion on-click.